# Use SVG Sprite in Vue JS as CSS Background Image

Tags: css, vue.js, svg

If I set up an SVG sprite file in a Vue JS HTML template like this, it works great:

```
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="~@/assets/images/icons.svg#edit"></use>
</svg>
```

And the `icons.svg` file looks something like this:

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="edit" viewbox="0 0 15 15">
    <g>...</g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

But if I try and use that same SVG fragment in a Vue CSS file like this:

```
.edit-icon{
  background:url('~@/assets/images/icons.svg#edit') no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
}
```

...it doesn't work. My assumption is that the browser can only traverse to the `#edit` symbol in HTML.

Is there a way to use this same SVG sprite method in a CSS background?

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use both `~` and `@` in the css import.

```
.edit-icon{
  background:url('@/assets/images/icons.svg#edit') no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Removing the `~` breaks the path and I get a `relative module was not found` error.